# how to update dynamically generated form in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have a code here where I have to do update operation. I'm generating the form fields dynamically based on the result of get operation. The form fields are pre-populated. On change event on the input field in triggering an error data.map is not a function on keypress. I can change for single fields with different names. But unable to update json array state. Please help. I have attached the code snippet below.

```
export default class PocDetail extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
   this.state={
     isLoading:true,
     editData:[],
   };
 }


 componentDidMount(){
   this.renderData();
 }

 renderData(){
  var self = this;
  const getOrgId = 
  window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  const url = "some api";
  get(url+"Organisation/"+getOrgId+"/pointOfContacts/").then(function (response) {
   console.log(response.data);
   self.setState({
     editData:response.data,
     isLoading:false
   })
 }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
   });
 }

 putData =(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
 }


//edit permission for input fields
  inputChangedHandler = (event) => {
  this.setState({ editData: { ...this.state.editData,[event.target.name]:event.target.value} });
  // May be call for search result
  }


 //the view
 render() {
   const {isLoading,editData} = this.state;
   if(isLoading){
    return <Loader />;
   }
   return (
    <div>
     <Row style={{paddingTop:'20px',paddingBottom:'40px',marginLeft:'auto',marginRight:'auto'}}>
        <Col lg="8" md="8" sm="8">
          <Form id="bankForm" onSubmit={this.putData}>
            <ToastContainer store={ToastStore}/>
            {
              editData.map(data=>{
              return(<Row key={data.id}>
                <Col lg="6" md="6" sm="6">
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label className="createLabelStyle" for="title">Title</Label>
                    <Input className="createInputStyle" type="text" name="title" id="title" autoComplete="off" value={data.title} onChange={(event)=>this.inputChangedHandler(event)} required/>
                  </FormGroup>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label className="createLabelStyle" for="first_name">First name</Label>
                    <Input className="createInputStyle" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value={data.first_name} onChange={(event)=>this.inputChangedHandler(event)} autoComplete="off" required/>
                  </FormGroup>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label className="createLabelStyle" for="contact_number">Contact Number</Label>
                    <Input className="createInputStyle" type="text" name="contact_number" id="contact_number" autoComplete="off" value={(data.contact_number==null)?"":data.contact_number} onChange={(event)=>this.inputChangedHandler(event)} required/>
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
                <Col lg="6" md="6" sm="6">
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label className="createLabelStyle" for="email">Email ID</Label>
                    <Input className="createInputStyle" type="text" name="email" value={data.email} onChange={(event)=>this.inputChangedHandler(event)} id="email"  autoComplete="off" required/>
                  </FormGroup>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label className="createLabelStyle" for="last_name">Last name</Label>
                     <Input className="createInputStyle" type="text" name="last_name" value={data.last_name} onChange={(event)=>this.inputChangedHandler(event)} id="last_name"  autoComplete="off" required/>
                   </FormGroup>
                 </Col>
             </Row>);
               })
             }
             <Button className="createSubmitStyle">Add</Button>{' '}
             <Button className="createSubmitStyle">Update</Button>
           </Form>
         </Col>
     </Row>
   </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you try console logging and check what `editData` is before you call `.map` on it.  If it is not a list, then you will get that error. 
You should check the api response as well. If it is not returning in the format that you expect, you will be setting `editData` wrongly

Comment: editdata is responding a json array properly. Its the problem with onchange input field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution. Adding this code below solved the problem. I needed to add index with map to update the property value of object.

```
  inputChangedHandler(i,event){
    let data = [...this.state.editData];
    data[i][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    console.log(data[i][event.target.name]);
    this.setState({editData:data});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the renderData function variable editData is an Array that's why it is rendering your form properly but in the inputChangedHandler function you are updating editData to an Object hence the issue

Answer (score 0):

Please try this snippet:

editData!=undefined &&editData.map(data=>{});

Comment: All I want to do is update json array onchange event. correspond event should change